# Running a basic scanner program

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to write a program that given the amount of liquid, I can compute the amount of cups of water and teaspoons of sugar, which are four times the amount of liquid. Why won't this program I wrote work, and could any of you possibly steer me in the right direction? I have been working on this for hours and can't seem to locate the problem.

Thanks!

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
// Scanner scan = new scanner(system.in);
double liquid, cups;
double teasoons;
System.out.println("Dishwashing liquid?");
liquid = scan.nextdouble();
cups = 4*liquid;
teaspoons = 4*liquid
System.out.println(cups+teaspoons and grams);
scan.close();

}
}
```

Comment: Your class can be named whatever even if public, you don't need to name it `Main`... Actually your simple code has many issues that should be discussed on SO instead of Programmers.

Comment: One main point is that java is case-sensitive on identifiers you need to be more attentive on what you type.

Comment: `throws java.lang.Exception` is a bad habit to get into.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your help. So I modified the code a little bit and everything looks great, except now when I run it, it says the standard input is empty? What does that mean? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
System.out.println(cups+teaspoons and grams);
```

to this

```
System.out.println(cups+ "teaspoons and grams");
```

Also, be carefull with class names, they have to be begin with a capital letter.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(system.in);
```

All in all your code should look like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    double liquid, cups;
    double teaspoons;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(system.in);

    System.out.println("Dishwashing liquid?");
    liquid = scan.nextdouble();
    cups = 4*liquid;
    teaspoons = 4*liquid
    System.out.println(cups + "teaspoons and grams");
    scan.close();

}
```

Comment: Class names don't *have* to begin with a capital letter; that's just a convention.  But when you refer to an existing class like `Scanner`, you have to spell its name correctly, including its capitalization.

Comment: Well, what you mean is a declaration. I mean the name of the class, in this case the Scanner class.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your help. So I modified the code a little bit and everything looks great, except now when I run it, it says the standard input is empty? What does that mean? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
double liquid, cups;
double teaspoons;
System.out.println("Dishwashing liquid?");
liquid = scan.nextDouble();
cups = 4*liquid;
teaspoons = 4*liquid;
System.out.println(cups+"teaspoons and grams");
scan.close();

}
}
```